# Hot to make a class for my program JAVA

Tags: java, class

Ok so I've been making this program of mine to get some inventory data, all from scratch, because the professor's helping code is rubbish. But I am a bit stuck. as you can see below, my code is going to pass some strings to a class called address which will basically compile that information into a single variable.

But I need some help writing that class, now I know most of the posters here won't write the code for me. I am not asking you to write it for me, I am asking you to tell me how I can do it, show an example. It would help me quite a lot. Also it would mean that later I can make the manufacturer pretty much alone, although I know I will mess up a bit on it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

class Inventory
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        Database dpl = new Database();

final String[] MENU_OPTIONS = {"exit", "Add product", "Sell product", "Delete product", "Modify product",
                               "Display information"};
final String MENU_NAME = "Inventory";

boolean active = true;

        while(active)
        {


String selection = promptInventory(MENU_NAME, MENU_OPTIONS);

//logic


      switch ( selection )
      {
         case  "exit"         : active = false;
                             break;

         case  "Add product"  : // Creating an order and adding this order to the database
                                 IO.display("Add new product", "New product", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                String street = IO.getWord("Enter street address");
                                String city = IO.getWord("Enter city");
                                 String state = IO.getWord("Enter state");
                                 String zip = IO.getWord("Enter zip code");
                                Address addr = new Address(street, city, state, zip);

                                // Company stuff
                                String company_name =  IO.getWord("Enter name of the company");
                                 Manufacturer m = new Manufacturer(addr, company_name);



                             break;

         case  "Sell product" : 
                             break;

      }//switch

  }//while loop    

}//main

public static String promptInventory(String MName, String[] options)
   {
      int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                                             "Enter your Transaction Type",
                                             MName,
                                             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                                             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                             null, options, options[0] );
      return (String)options[selection];
   }//prompt   




}//inventory class
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: And explain your question a little more please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SomeClass {
//method that accept your string and perform action
public void method(String str){
   //TODO Action 
   }
}
```

To make it work you need to create an object of this class in the main.

```
SomeClass someclass = new SomeClass;
someclass.method(yourdata);
```

Comment: I think I have something like that.

Comment: Clarify your question then